# How to Make Check box is checked

Tags: php, checkbox

How can I make my check box is checked using PHP, when i visit the page later i want previously selected check boxes are checked

```
<input  name="product[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Session as

```
    <?php
session_start();
$session_products = array();
if(array_key_exists("products", $_SESSION)) 
{
  if($_SESSION["products"] != null)
  {
    $session_products = $_SESSION["products"];
  }
}

?>
```

Change your code as follows

```
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if(in_array("1", $session_products)) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `checked`.

Here an example:

```
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" checked />
```

By the way, your `value=1` seems to be wrong. Normally you use `value to distinguish items.

Example:

```
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="dvd" checked />
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="cd" />
```

Answer (score 0):

to do something like this 
with **php**

```
<input  name="product[]"  type="checkbox" value="1" <?php echo ($value =="1") ? "checked" : ""; ?> />
```

where `$value` is the value from database